# Malloc two structs for cache simulator

Tags: c, caching, memory, struct, malloc

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t valid_bit;
    uint32_t tag;
    uint32_t index;
    uint32_t data[4];
} Block;

// Final cache structure
typedef struct {
    Block* blocks;
} Cache;

Cache myCache;

myCache.blocks = (Block*) malloc(noOfBlocks * sizeof(Block));

for (int i = 0; i < noOfBlocks; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
           myCache.blocks[i].valid_bit = 0;
           myCache.blocks[i].tag = 0;
           myCache.blocks[i].index = i;
           myCache.blocks[i].data[j] = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is how malloc should be used. Do I have to malloc my data[] too in order to access it later on?

Also, is this how to initialize my cache?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Arrays doesn't have to be allocated explicitly.

Comment: On another note, please do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the code you show. Do you really need to assign to e.g. `myCache.blocks[i].valid_bit` four times?

Comment: In general it's good practice to use `x = malloc(sizeof *x * count);`, without casting, and without specifying the size of the struct explicitly. The same goes for `memset`, e.g. `memset(x, 0, sizeof *x * count)`. So consider replacing `myCache.blocks = (Block*) malloc(noOfBlocks * sizeof(Block));`  with `myCache.blocks = malloc(sizeof *myCache.blocks * noOfBlocks);`.

Answer (score 1):

The first three statements in the `for` loop should be in the outer loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfBlocks; i++) {
    myCache.blocks[i].valid_bit = 0;
    myCache.blocks[i].tag = 0;
    myCache.blocks[i].index = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        myCache.blocks[i].data[j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Also make sure to free the memory when you're done using it:

```
free(myCache.blocks);
```

Other than that it's fine.

> Do I have to malloc my data[] too in order to access it later on?

No, arrays aren't allocated dynamically.